# Get first node name in XML in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, element, xelement

I have the below in my XML file:

```
<Resources>
    <a>123.png</a>
</Resources>
<Resources>
    <b>123.png</b>
</Resources>
<Resources>
    <c>123.png</c>
</Resources>
```

I want to get the first node name of "`Resource`" which is "`a`", "`b`", "`c`".

But when I do this:

```
foreach (var downloadFile in downloadFiles.Elements("Resources"))
{
    if (downloadFile.Value != null)
    {
        string fileName = downloadFile.FirstNode.ToString();
     }
}
```

It will return whole line `<a>123.png</a>`.

How do I get the firstnode name which is "`a`"?

Comment: You tagged `xelement`. Do you use XElement or XmlElement?

Comment: Xelement dear friend

Comment: By the way, be careful with terminology. You ask for *node* - this is not the same as *element*, because node can be: XText (which also holds XCData), XDocumentType, XContainer (which holds XElement and XDocument), XProcessingInstruction and XComment. In my answer I test the type of the node - if it's not XElement (since only XElement [and XDocument, but we don't consider it] can have name), then it's thrown out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast XNode to XElement in order to get the element name. XElement is derived from XNode, but XNode has no Name property, while XElement has.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xml = XElement.Parse(@"
<root>
    <Resources>
        <a>123.png</a>
    </Resources>
    <Resources>
        <b>123.png</b>
    </Resources>
    <Resources>
        <c>123.png</c>
    </Resources>
</root>");

            var resourceElements = xml.Elements("Resources");
            foreach (var resourceElement in resourceElements)
            {
                // Cast from XNode to XElement
                var desiredElement = resourceElement.FirstNode as XElement; 
                if (desiredElement != null) // In case first node is not an element, but for instance text or comment
                {
                    var elementName = desiredElement.Name;
                    Console.WriteLine(elementName);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(@"
<root>
    <Resources>
        <a>123.png</a>
    </Resources>
    <Resources>
        <b>123.png</b>
    </Resources>
    <Resources>
        <c>123.png</c>
    </Resources>
</root>");

var all_first =
    xml
    .Elements("Resources") //get all Resources children
    .Select(r => r.FirstNode) //take first node of Resources element
    .OfType<XElement>() //take only XElement (rather XText, XComment etc.)
    .Select(f => f.Name) //finally, take name of the first element
    ;
all_first.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Fixed :)

Comment: This code does not give the desired result. Output is
  
`<a>123.png</a>  
<b>123.png</b>  
<c>123.png</c>`

Comment: @Bouke OP says *I want to get the first node name of "Resource" which is "a", "b", "c"*. So, what's wrong?

Comment: Output should only contain element names, your code also outputs element content.

Comment: @Bouke Fixed! :)

Comment: Now it works. In fact your code is now the same as the code in my answer (mine is less terse though).

Comment: @Bouke Although code *does* work for the original example which OP gave, in reality XNode can be anything other than XElement - for instance, XText. Since OP didn't give us any clue, I assume that the first node will always be XElement. :)

Comment: That's true. Just updated my code. When the node is not an XElement but for instance XText, the cast would result in null.

Comment: @Bouke I have updated code which takes into consideration the type of the Node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XML document:

```
XmlDocument oDoc = XmlDocument.Load(yourXmlHere);
XmlNodeList oMainNodes = oDoc.SelectNodes("/Resources");
// Resource's first subnode (a)
foreach(XmlNode oMainNode in oMainNodes)
{
   XmlNode oResourceNode = oMainNode.ChildNodes[0];
   // node a
   string sResourceName = oResourceNode.Name;
}
```

Comment: hi there.. I cannot use selectsinglenode because I have lots of "resource" node. (I edited my question). That's why I use foreach loop. How guys?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<Resources><a>123.png</a></Resources>");
Console.WriteLine(xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Name);
```

It is not tested, but it should work.

Comment: hi there.. I cannot use selectsinglenode because I have lots of "resource" node. (I edited my question). That's why I use foreach loop. How guys?

Comment: OP is using XElement rather XmlElement. Please, see comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `XElement.Name` property instead of `XElement.ToString()`.

```
XElement element = new XElement("a", "123.png");
element.Name.ToString() // returns "a"
element.ToString() // returns "<a>123.png</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Descendants* method :

```
 XElement element = XElement.Parse(xmlString)
        .Descendants()
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Giving that xmlString is your XML file.

Comment: Yes. In this example I considered the XML as a string.

Comment: And what's your output?

Comment: It will return an XElement.

Comment: OP needs names of all first nodes. I encourage you to read question carefully.